# Recreating the master boot record of a Ubuntu USB installation?

Tags: ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, unetbootin

I copied my unetbootin installation onto my Windows 7 machine, and formatted the drive and put something completely different on it.  Then later I copied the installation it back on to the USB drive again.

Now when I try to boot from the USB drive, it states that the master boot record is missing.  I originally created the USB stick with unetbootin.  Is there any way to restore the master boot record, or get back the files I had stored in my home directory on the USB drive?

P.S. I'm not sure if this belongs on [SU](http://www.superuser.com/) or "[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)", please take a approiate action.

Comment: Well here's a way of getting the files back at least...http://askubuntu.com/questions/86789/which-file-on-a-usb-live-installation-made-with-unetbootin-persists-file-informa/86868#comment99409_86868 (forgot I asked that) might as well leave the question here just incase someone knows how.

Answer (score 0):

I think your various options are in [Grub2: Reinstalling GRUB2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling_GRUB2) at the Ubuntu Documentation site. (...regardless that the difficulty involves your USB stick not your hard disk or SSD.)